# How to fight the heat during summertime?

Tags: temperature, summer

So it's summertime now, and it's gettin' real hot where I live ! What do you do to cool down the room, or just stop being hot, without having to spend hundred of dollars on air conditioning ?

I suggest that everybody who knows a solution post it as an answer, so we can fight the heat together !

Comment: Is your problem excessive heat or excessive humidity? The two are often confused. Most often, your body will sweat to cool you down when you're too hot. You might be too humid. Look through the answers already provided here. Then, if you can't find the answer reword your question so that we can work on it.

Answer (score 0):

### Wet your body

Pour some (cold) water on your arms, legs, face and neck. This way, when the water will evaporate, it will take energy from your body and you will feel cold, just like when you come out of a swimming pool.

The only problem with this method is that you'll have to repeat it every 5-10 minutes. I suggest that you always keep a bucket of water and a towel close to you, so you don't have to go to the tap nonstop.